# Airflow Broken DAG, py4j.protocol.py4jerror

Tags: airflow

I'm learning how to use Airflow for a university project. I created my DAG and all jobs using pycharm and everything works well there: my objective is to create a basic data architecture that extracts data from a public API, transforms it and index it into Elasticsearch to create visualizations.

Unfortunately, the DAG is not being imported to airflow properly. I get the following error message:

```
Broken DAG: [/Users/soyuz/airflow/dags/big_data_project_dag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/soyuz/airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 190, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/Users/soyuz/airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 334, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o28.parquet
```

When I refresh localhost many times, my DAG appears, but then when I trigger it I receive this error message :

```
    eTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/soyuz/airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/soyuz/airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/soyuz/airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/soyuz/airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/Users/soyuz/airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/www/auth.py", line 47, in decorated
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/soyuz/airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/www/decorators.py", line 81, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/soyuz/airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 75, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/soyuz/airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/www/views.py", line 1930, in trigger
    if unpause and dag.is_paused:
  File "/Users/soyuz/airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 1264, in is_paused
    warnings.warn(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/warnings.py", line 109, in _showwarnmsg
    sw(msg.message, msg.category, msg.filename, msg.lineno,
  File "/Users/soyuz/airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 126, in custom_show_warning
    write_console.print(msg, soft_wrap=True)
  File "/Users/soyuz/airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rich/console.py", line 1715, in print
    self._buffer.extend(new_segments)
  File "/Users/soyuz/airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rich/console.py", line 869, in __exit__
    self._exit_buffer()
  File "/Users/soyuz/airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rich/console.py", line 827, in _exit_buffer
    self._check_buffer()
  File "/Users/soyuz/airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rich/console.py", line 2039, in _check_buffer
    self.file.write(text)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I think the error is not related to code, cause there aren't errors on pycharm and I get the expected result. Could you help me solve this issue please? Let me know if there is important information missing on my question!

My python version is 3.9
Airflow 2.4.2

EDIT. DAG code

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

from lib.fetch_data_from_api import fetch_data_from_api
from lib.data_from_insee_activites import get_activite_data
from lib.data_from_insee_cj import get_cj_data
from lib.data_from_insee_communes import get_communes_data
from lib.data_from_insee_communes2 import get_communes_data2
from lib.raw_to_fmt_sirene import convert_raw_to_formatted
from lib.combine_data import combine_data
from lib.data_to_elastic import data_to_elastic_activites
from lib.data_to_elastic_categorie import data_to_elastic_categories
from lib.data_to_elastic_cj import data_to_elastic_cj
from lib.data_to_elastic_communes import data_to_elastic_communes
from lib.data_to_elastic_creation import data_to_elastic_creation
from lib.data_to_elastic_effectifs import data_to_elastic_effectifs

with DAG(
        'big_data_project_dag',
        default_args={
            'depends_on_past': False,
            'email_on_failure': False,
            'email_on_retry': False,
            'retries': 2,
            'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=15),
        },
        description='Load monthly data from SIRENE API',
        schedule='@monthly',
        start_date=datetime(2022, 11, 4),
        catchup=False,
        tags=['example'],
) as dag:
    dag.doc_md = """
       This is my first DAG in airflow.
   """

    def task1():
        print("Hello Airflow - This is Task 1")

    t1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='apiSirene_to_raw',
        python_callable=fetch_data_from_api,
        op_kwargs={'task_number': 'task1'}
    )
    t2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='get_static_data1',
        python_callable=get_activite_data,
        op_kwargs={'task_number': 'task2'}
    )

    t3 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='get_static_data2',
        python_callable=get_cj_data,
        op_kwargs={'task_number': 'task3'}
    )

    t4 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='get_static_data3',
        python_callable=get_communes_data,
        op_kwargs={'task_number': 'task4'}
    )

    t5 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='get_static_data4',
        python_callable=get_communes_data2,
        op_kwargs={'task_number': 'task5'}
    )

    t6 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='raw_to_formatted',
        python_callable=convert_raw_to_formatted,
        op_kwargs={'task_number': 'task6'}
    )

    t7 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='combine_data',
        python_callable=combine_data,
        op_kwargs={'task_number': 'task7'}
    )

    t8 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='index1',
        python_callable=data_to_elastic_activites,
        op_kwargs={'task_number': 'task8'}
    )

    t9 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='index2',
        python_callable=data_to_elastic_categories,
        op_kwargs={'task_number': 'task9'}
    )

    t10 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='index3',
        python_callable=data_to_elastic_cj,
        op_kwargs={'task_number': 'task10'}
    )

    t11 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='index4',
        python_callable=data_to_elastic_communes,
        op_kwargs={'task_number': 'task11'}
    )

    t12 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='index5',
        python_callable=data_to_elastic_creation,
        op_kwargs={'task_number': 'task12'}
    )

    t13 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='index6',
        python_callable=data_to_elastic_effectifs,
        op_kwargs={'task_number': 'task13'}
    )


t1>>t6
t6>>t7
t2>>t7
t3>>t7
t4>>t7
t5>>t7
t7>>t8
t7>>t9
t7>>t10
t7>>t11
t7>>t12
t7>>t13
```

Comment: can you add the source code of your dag? it looks like you're doing something with pyspark in the dag script, and it's braking the dag

Comment: Hello and thank you for your comment. I added the code, I'm using pyarrow in task 7 to combine the different data sources, I'm not sure if it's the same think as pyspark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's recommended to avoid the top import and import directly in the method body when you want to use specific python packages for an Airflow task:

```py
# avoid
from module import method
def func():
    method()

# use instead
def func():
    from module import method
    method()
```

In this case you can totally avoid the problems with your scheduler and webserver while processing the dag script, and if the package is not installed in those services:

- with python operator: the task will fail without affecting the other tasks
- with other operator (ex: python venv operator) or k8s executor with custom image, the task will pass in its env without any problem

So if you import some not built-in modules at the top of your modules, and you use them in the 13 methods you are importing in the dag script, try to move theses import statements to the body of each method.

This solution can help you to avoid the dag files processing problems, but it doesn't solve the py4j problem, so if after moving the import statements to the methods bodies and when you trigger the dag run, the task 7 fails with a similar error, you need to check your pyspark lib and check if the jdk is installed in the host where the workers are running (docker image if you are using docker), but I recommend to avoid installing it and run this task in an isolated env using `KubernetesPodOperator` or another similar operator (`DockerOperator`, ...)

Comment: Thank you ! it solved my import problems. I'm still facing the [Errno 32] Broken pipe error.